# How do I have my lambda functions make outbound requests from a static IP?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I've seen plenty saying I need to setup a VPC and NAT but there's no guide I can find that covers exactly how to do that.

I have no experience with VPC, so it's all pretty confusing. I tried following http://techblog.financialengines.com/2016/09/26/aws-lambdas-with-a-static-outgoing-ip/ but it didn't work...

NB: the service we have to send data to requires IP whitelisting, that's why we're going through this process.

Edit: the issue with the NAT gateway I setup is that my lambda function can no longer make any outbound connections

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a sufficient description of a problem.  A NAT Gateway is the correct solution; see the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).  To troubleshoot a specific problem, we need a specific description of it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've updated the question. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Your Lambda function is on subnets X and Y which are private subnets.  Those subnets use a route table that points to a NAT Gateway on subnet Z which is a public subnet whose route table points it's default route to the Internet Gateway.  The documentation is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I found the issue thanks to your comment. I was connecting my lambda to the *public* subnet instead of the *private* subnet.

Comment: that's the new architecture proposed by AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-a-static-outbound-ip-address-using-a-lambda-function-amazon-vpc-and-a-serverless-architecture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this guide](http://techblog.financialengines.com/2016/09/26/aws-lambdas-with-a-static-outgoing-ip/) worked after some debugging.

The mistake I had made was pointing the lambda at the *public* subnet not the *private* subnet.